# Загрузить картинку из angular клиента на spring boot (java) сервер

Tags: typescript, angular

При выборе изображения на клиенте (Angular), я хочу передать изображение серверу (java), но маршрутизация в angular постоянно перекидывает на главную страницу моего сайта (пытаюсь скачать с http://localhost:4200/files/{название.формат}, но перекидывает на localhost:4200), что не позволяет выкачать изображение серверу. Подскажите, пожалуйста, может быть в angular есть что-то вроде условной маршрутизации?

Из app-routing уже всё перелопатил и не вышло, поэтому обращаюсь к вам.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: "login",
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: "signup",
    component: SignupComponent
  },
  {
    path: "category/:id",
    component: CategoryViewComponent
  },
  {
    path: "cart",
    component: CartComponent
  },
  {
    path: "myorder",
    component: MyorderComponent
  },
  {
    path: "admin",
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: "category",
        component: CategoryComponent
      },
      {
        path: "supplier",
        component: SupplierComponent
      },
      {
        path: "product",
        component: ProductComponent
      },
      {
        path: "order",
        component: OrderComponent
      },
      {
        path: "user",
        component: UserComponent
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: "**",
    redirectTo: ""
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Пробовал на проекте без маршрутизации и всё работало.

Comment: а что вы ожидаете от localhost:4200/files/format если этот порт слушает webpack, а спринг у вас однозначно слушает другой порт

Comment: но в другом примере всё сработало

Comment: в каком другом?

Comment: который нашёл в интернете:https://grokonez.com/java-integration/angular-6-upload-get-multipartfile-spring-boot-example

Comment: в примере используется прокси к тому же на все урлы, с роутером это не прокатит

Comment: а есть другое тогда решение данной ситуации?

Comment: Как мне передать иным путём изображение на сервер?

Comment: не проксировать

Comment: а можно код? просто не совсем понимаю идею

Comment: у вас спринг слушает какой-то порт - 8080 или какой-то другой, шлите прямо на localhost:8080/files/format запрос

Comment: сейчас попробую

Comment: появился вопрос, как из angular мне отправлять изображение на порт 8080, а не 4200?